# macOS Sierra won't install and complains on the disk

Tags: hard-drive, install, partition, startup, macos

After downloading and running the installer, I met with the problem when the installer is asking "Select the disk where you want to install macOS". My default OS X disk which runs El Capitan normally grayed out, and when I click on it, it just complains "This disk cannot be used to start up your computer".

My Macbook pro's model is Early 2015, so I don't think the problem lies in model compatibility. I partitioned the 128G APPLE SSD Disk to a 100G "OS X" disk (running El Capitan) and an extra part not showing up in Disk Utility, in which I installed Ubuntu Linux. I don't know if this is the cause of the problem...

Comment: Can you please post a picture sharing what the error looks like?

Comment: Open System Settings -> startup disk and check whether your system drive is checked as startup volume. Restart and try again please.